# How to make a button in a game class with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I have been trying to make a button in a class with tkinter, but the button doesn't appear. The rest of the game is fine. I is just when i try to add a quit button in the game class it doesn't appear. I am using python 3.4.3 . I am make a game that you pop bubbles with a submarine. I have tried `self.button_quit = tkinter.Button(window, text="Quit")` and this is the class code:

```
class Game():
    height = 500
    width = 800
    mid_x = width / 2
    mid_y = height / 2
    bonus_score = 700
    bubble_chance = 10
    gap = 100
    time_limit = 30
    speed = 0.01

    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.bonus = 0
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.window.title('Bubble Blaster')
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.window, width=self.width,
                height=self.height, bg='darkblue')
        self.end = time.time() + self.time_limit
        Text(self.canvas,50,30,'TIME')
        Text(self.canvas,150,30,'SCORE')
        self.gui_score = Text(self.canvas,150,50)
        self.gui_time = Text(self.canvas,50,50)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.bubbles = list()
        self.ship = Ship(self.canvas)
        self.ship.move(self.mid_x, self.mid_y)

    def coords_of(cid):
        pos = c.coords(cid)
        x = (pos[0] + pos[2]) / 2
        y = (pos[1] + pos[3]) / 2
        return x, y

    def create_bubble(self):
        x = self.width + self.gap
        y = random.randint(0,self.height)
        self.bubbles.append(Bubble(self.canvas,x,y))

    def move_bubbles(self):
        for bubble in self.bubbles:
            bubble.move(-bubble.speed,0)

    def destroy_bubble(self,bubble):
        self.bubbles.remove(bubble)
        bubble.destroy()

    def clean_up_bubbles(self):
        for bubble in self.bubbles:
            if bubble.x < -self.gap:
                self.destroy_bubble(bubble)
    def buttons(self):
        self.button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Quit")
        self.button1.tkinter.pack()
    def run(self):
        while time.time() < self.end:
            if random.randint(1, self.bubble_chance) == 1:
                self.create_bubble()
            self.move_bubbles()
            self.clean_up_bubbles()
            self.score += self.ship_bubble_collision()
            if (int(self.score / self.bonus_score)) > self.bonus:
                self.bonus += 1
                self.end += self.time_limit
            self.time_left = int(self.end - time.time())
            self.update_gui()
            self.window.update()
            self.ship.step()
            time.sleep(self.speed)
        Text(self.canvas,self.mid_x, self.mid_y,'GAME OVER',
                font=('Helvetica',30))
        Text(self.canvas,self.mid_x, self.mid_y + 30,
                'Score ' + str(self.score))
        Text(self.canvas,self.mid_x, self.mid_y + 45,'Bonus Time ' + 
                str(self.bonus * self.time_limit))
        input()

    def distance(self,x1,y1,x2,y2):
        return math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)

    def ship_bubble_collision(self):
        points = 0
        for bubble in self.bubbles:
            distance = self.distance(self.ship.x,self.ship.y,\
                    bubble.x,bubble.y)
            boundary = self.ship.radius + bubble.radius
            if distance < boundary:
                points += bubble.radius + bubble.speed
                self.destroy_bubble(bubble)
        return points

    def update_gui(self):
        self.gui_score.update(str(self.score))
        self.gui_time.update(str(self.time_left))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Game().run()
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? What does it do? What do you expect it to do differently?

Comment: Well, one obvious reason it doesn't work is that you never call the `buttons` method that contains the button creation code. I'm not sure when you want the button to appear, so you'll have to decide where that call should be (or if the code should be moved somewhere else, like into `__init__`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

`buttons()`

Where you need it to be called. Buttons can't appear without being called!
If you need more info on def, click [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm).

Also for future questions, please elaborate on your question more. It is hard to tell exactly what you are asking.